# How to export metadata from a running WCF service

Tags: c#, wsdl, wcf, svcutil.exe

I wish to send the service metadata of a running WCF service to a third party developer,
so he'll be able to create a proxy on his end.

At the moment the service is accessible from my local machine only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line tool [Web Service Discoverty Tool (disco.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy2a3ybs(VS.80).aspx) to get the wsdl from your service which can be sent to the third party.